# Pandas Reindex - Fill Column with Missing Values

Tags: python, pandas

I tried several examples of this topic but with no results. I'm reading a DataFrame like:

```
Code,Counts
10006,5
10011,2
10012,26
10013,20
10014,17
10015,2
10018,2
10019,3
```

How can I get another DataFrame like:

```
Code,Counts
10006,5
10007,NaN
10008,NaN
...
10011,2
10012,26
10013,20
10014,17
10015,2
10016,NaN
10017,NaN
10018,2
10019,3
```

Basically filling the missing values of the 'Code' Column? I tried the `df.reindex()` method but I can't figure out how it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set the index to you 'Code' column, then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) by passing in a new array based on your current index, [`arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) accepts a start and stop param (you need to add 1 to the end) and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) this assumes that your 'Code' values are already sorted:

```
In [21]:

df.set_index('Code', inplace=True)
df = df.reindex(index = np.arange(df.index[0], df.index[-1] + 1)).reset_index()
df
Out[21]:
     Code  Counts
0   10006       5
1   10007     NaN
2   10008     NaN
3   10009     NaN
4   10010     NaN
5   10011       2
6   10012      26
7   10013      20
8   10014      17
9   10015       2
10  10016     NaN
11  10017     NaN
12  10018       2
13  10019       3
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But what if I have to add back data (e.g. from 0 to 10006) in the 'Code' index?

Comment: You should be able to `concat`, in which case before the call to `reset_index` , set the index to 'Code' for your other data and then call `pd.concat([df, other_df]).reset_index()` this should stack them on top each other, hope this is clear

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is useful, but my previous comment was not clear. I do not have to "add" data, but simply go back to 0 with my actual DataFrame... I have a database with unsorted and non-contiguous data, the only thing I know is the lower 'Code' value (0) and the higher, but during the analyses the lower 'Code' value is not constant (for instance right now the dataset starts from 108 to 15000, and I would like to fill values inside and outside the limits).

Comment: I think you should still be to reindex still even before your first value, I just tried it and it still works fine

Comment: You could also do it with a merge.

import pandas as pd

Dict = {'Counts':[5,2,26,20,17,2,2,3],
  "code":[10006,10011,10012,10013,10014,10015,10018,10019]}

df = pd.DataFrame(Dict).set_index('code')
Filled = pd.DataFrame(range(min(df.index),max(df.index)+1))
df2 = pd.merge(Filled,df,left_on=0,right_index=True,how='left')